# Find an appropriate set and a function such that neither is a subset of the other.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I'm supposed to find a function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ and a set $A\subseteq X$ such that neither $f(A^{c})\subseteq f(A)^{c}$ nor $f(A)^{c}\subseteq f(A^{c})$.

I really don't know what to look for or start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always try some finite examples first:

$X=Y=\{1,2,3,4\}$, $A=\{1,2\}$, $f(1)=1, f(2)=2,f(3)=2, f(4)=3$.

Then $f[A]= \{1,2\}$, $f[A^c]=\{2,3\}$, $f[A]^c = \{3,4\}$, so neither inclusion holds between $f[A^c]$ and $f[A]^c$. Found by some trial and error.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but do you think this is possible with a "formula" function like $f(x)=x^2$? I'm on this exercise now, and did try finite sets, but just couldn't fund any formula...